# GoogleAPIClient Connection in onCreate vs onStart

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-api-client, android-googleapiclient

Excerpt from [Google API Client documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#enableAutoManage(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)),

```
public GoogleApiClient.Builder enableAutoManage (FragmentActivity
fragmentActivity, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
unresolvedConnectionFailedListener)
```

> Enables automatic lifecycle management in a support library
>   FragmentActivity that connects the client in onStart() and disconnects
>   it in onStop().
>
> It handles user recoverable errors appropriately and calls
>   onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult) on the
>   unresolvedConnectionFailedListener if the ConnectionResult has no
>   resolution. This eliminates most of the boiler plate associated with
>   using GoogleApiClient.

While it may sound a bit naive, but my **question** is if this is an important step that we start the connection of a GoogleAPIClient in `onStart` method? Is there any harm if I make a connection in `onCreate` instead? I have multiple scenarios where I see the need to connect to the googleApiClient in `onCreate` due to the legacy code. I have also tried making a connection in onCreate and that works(I dont see any crashes). Is that a bad idea? So why is it necessary or important to start a connection in `onStart` and stop the connection in `onStop`?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this thread: [What does onStart() really do? - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302220/what-does-onstart-really-do-android)

> `onStart()` is called when activity resumes from stopped state. For example, if you have activity A and starts activity B from it, then activity A will be paused (`onPause()`) and then stopped (`onStop()`) and moved to back stack. After this, if you press Back into your activity B, B will be paused(`onPause()`), stopped (`onStop()`) and destroyed(`onDestroy()`), and activity A will be restored from back stack, started (`onStart()`) and resumed(`onResume()`). As you can see, system will not call `onCreate()` for A again.
>
> How to use `onStart()`? For example, you should unregister listeners for GPS, sensors, etc in `onStop()` and register again in `onStart()`. If you register it in `onCreate()` and unregister in `onDestroy()`, then GPS service will work always and it will drain battery.

It was also stated that the main role of [`onStart()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for) is when the activity is called after being paused. If `onCreate()` is called then all the initializations should be done again, by using `onStart()` we can initialize those things which had been uninitialized in `onstop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Moving code from `onStart` to `onCreate` will cause problems. Take for example, an application that uses location services to display location on a map. This is a well-behaved application that stops using location services `onStop`, when the user is no longer using the application.

1. User starts application (`onCreate`, `onStart`)
2. User goes away (`onStop`)
3. User comes back to application before it is destroyed (`onStart`, but not `onCreate`)

If you connect only upon `onCreate`, this means the application is not connected after step #3. The user will be using the application without the correct functionality because `onCreate` may not be called upon returning to an application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mattm. But if you lets say handle the connection by yourself, it doesnt cause any problems? This is only a recommendation correct not a must do right? Running in Exceptions, etc?

Comment: @Ahmed In the example I have provided, the application will not crash but will fail to function. This happens even if you manage the connection yourself.

Comment: Then what will be a perfect solution? On a separate note: EnableAutoManage doesn't seem to be stable either.